# Not able to install rainbow kit

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, rainbowkit

[image: Getting errors while installing the rainbow kit]
How to deal with these errors to install and integrate wallets

Comment: Please, next time past the error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

Use yarn instead of npm.
First install yarn using `npm install --global yarn` then use `yarn add @rainbow-me/rainbowkit wagmi viem`.